# Call Exports.run async from a member phrase

Tags: discord.js

Please help me understand how can i call that ping.js from user input, like if a user type ping it will Trigger cuz of the aliases but if a user types a full phrase it won't trigger.

Or in a non headic question how can i implent this to work -> if (message.content.includes('ping'))

Sorry in advance and thanks a lot

**ping.js**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const colors = require('../lib/colors.json')

exports.run = async (client, message, args, level) => {
  try {
    const pingEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor(colors.default)
      .setFooter('ping)
      .addField(`${message.author.id}`, 'hey')

    const msg = await message.channel.send(pingEmbed)

    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor(colors.default)
      .addField('...',
      `${msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms`)

    msg.edit(embed)
  } catch (err) {
    message.channel.send('There was an error!\n' + err).catch()
  }
}

exports.conf = {
  enabled: true,
  aliases: ['ping'],
  guildOnly: false,
  permLevel: 'User'
}

exports.help = {
  name: 'ping,
  category: 'tools,
  description: 'ping pong',
  usage: 'ping'
}
```

Comment: It's weird that you made this command but don't know how to use it... Are you following any guide? What is currently stopping you from achieving your result? What have you tried that is not working? You can add this in by clicking the [edit] button. I'm asking because what you need is a command handler, but it's kind of a long thing to explain, and it's better if you follow a guide for that. If you need a guide you can take a look at [An Idiot's Guide](https://anidiots.guide/first-bot/a-basic-command-handler), which has a section where explains how to build a command handlers.

Comment: Yes, of course, I use guides and been working with discordjs for some time, 
Still, I have a lot to learn... lately, I created some files to handle my commands for not having a lot of my functions together, so i got stuck with that issue. 
I do have a commands handler and everything is working, i just wanted to know how can i make my bot trigger my commands when they type the aliases but from a phrase (sentence) and not only for 1 word on a txt channel

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to get your issue... Just one more question: by "from a phrase" you mean that you want the command to be triggered by every message that starts with your prefix + the command (or the aliases), or just any message that includes one of the aliases? Could you give a practical example?

Comment: or just any message that includes one of the aliases? -> exactly!
Could you give a practical example? ->
like "hey can i ping you" and it will trigger, like in a normal content.includes()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether a message contains any of the aliases you can just use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like this:

```js
let aliases = ['your', 'command', 'aliases']

client.on('message', message => {
  if (aliases.some(trigger => message.content.includes(trigger))) {
    // The message includes at least one of your keywords
  }
})
```

In this example is just declared `aliases`, but you can use the array from your command and integrate this method in your normal command handler.